# total number of facebook likes for the entire domain

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-fql, share

my website http://mismo.rs itself (as mismo.rs) have been shared 3 times.

but the children pages http://mismo.rs/7-zena-koje-menjaju-predstavu-o-lepoti/ have been shared 326 times for example,

another page http://mismo.rs/13-pravila-uspesnih-ljudi/ have been shared 12 times.

what i need is the total number of those shares on facebook.

PS: i know i can do it with fql joining several domains, but it will be a huge long request, if i join all urls on my website. so i would like to find some other option

Answer (score 0):

Each page/unique canonical URL is treated by Facebook as it's own object, and you will have to aggregate those figures yourself.

Maybe you can get similar insights that satisfy your needs by using [Facebook domain insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights/domains)

Comment: i wanna show that on a website. insights dont give me that chance